# Android Studio Development - Even the default app won't work -

Tags: android, android-studio

I have decided to try to learn some Android App Development however I am unable to follow even the most basic tutorial. My problem is that what ever I seem to do, the compiler complains about about the Manifest.

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

However, this happens when the project is **completely unchanged from when Android Studio** created it.

The Manifest is below which is also unchanged but is copied below any way.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Toby.projecttoolkit" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Can somebody shed some light on why this might be happening? Any help in this area would be really appreciated.

Many thanks
Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and I resolved it by changing the package name to begin with a lowercas later i.e use `toby.projecttoolkit` instead of `Toby.projecttoolkit`.

Apart from that the Manifest file looks fine.

Refactor the package, clean, refresh and build the project. Make sure your project as no errors and try to run it.

Comment: I have no idea why, but that appeared to work for me! Thank you

Comment: Good to know! Its a standard Java convention to write package names in lowercase so that they don't confuse or conflict with class names (which start with uppercase letters). I wonder why the sample project had such a package name.